# notepad ++ shows ucs-2LE while ubuntu FILE [file] shows UTF-16LE, I am confused?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, notepad++, ucs2, utf-16le

I am trying to convert the file generated from a `mssql` to utf-8. When I open the output of he `mssql` using notepad++ in windows server 2003 recognises the file as `UCS-2LE` I copied the file to a Ubuntu machine, using `file [file]` it shows that the encoding is `UTF-16LE`. 
Really confused, there must be some difference in encoding, as the names are different. 
But why do I see this in the same file. Its a `.csv` file generated from the mssql query.

Comment: Old question but I think the answer from benw is correct and should be marked as this - or is there still something "open" for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the most part, UTF-16 and UCS-2 are the same thing. There is no difference.

What it means is that each character is two bytes wide. "LE" stands for *little endian*, i.e. each two-byte character is stored with the low byte first.

If you want to convert to UTF-8, in Notepad++ click `Convert to UTF-8` in the Encoding menu, then save.

If your other programs choke on the file after doing this, or you see two garbage characters at the start of the file, then click `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM` instead.

Comment: UTF-16 characters are also 2 bytes wide as far as I know. Why `file [file]` in Ubuntu is showing me Utf-16LE? when I see the list of encodings `iconv -l` recognises I can see both the encodings available. Now I want to know when I convert from this encoding to `utf-8` encoding, what encoding shall I use as the input file encoding?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit, but I am trying to convert in Ubuntu machine, If you read my explanation carefully, you can see that I need to choose between one of the two encodings, to put it in the input encoding for the command `iconv -f [input encoding] -t [output encoding] [file]`. How would you suggest me in this case?

Comment: I converted the file using NOTEPAD++ to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM but later when I open the file It again shows the encoding to be ANSI instead of UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM encoding.

Comment: Is this still in Notepad++ or is this on the Ubuntu machine? I don't know anything about Ubuntu, but when UTF-8 without BOM is selected, the Notepad++ status bar should report the encoding to be `ANSI as UTF-8`.

Comment: Also, like I said, UTF-16 and UCS-2 are pretty much the same thing. Try both and see which one works.

Comment: If your file, saved as UTF8 / without BOM contains no special characters, its indistinguible from ASCII / ANSI. Software can only recognize by guessing the contents (or using BOM if present).