# How to read .csv file?

Tags: php, csv

I have [a CSV file](https://doc-0g-3c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/e89h1ao7i0ek94darljdbukfk53d1hag/ksagpe790hhdi0nekeo5m77o4k9p5nfc/1512496800000/08937516263340724306/10348935371739585948/1YHR-N1s3V2EtvAR6bWIAFx5CzR8xnLMP). If I open it with a standard text editor such as notepad or excel, I can read the strings. But I can't read it with my PHP code (there is a symbols font error). How can I fix it?

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("data.csv","r");

    while(! feof($file))
      {
          print_r(fgetcsv($file));
      }

    fclose($file);
 ?>
```

[My CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHR-N1s3V2EtvAR6bWIAFx5CzR8xnLMP/view?usp=sharing)

Thank all! I found the answer http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2008/05/18/reading-a-unicode-excel-file-in-php/

Comment: "symbols font error" Huh? What is the error.

Comment: Error like TDMi�n T�y Na

Comment: I downloaded your CSV file, ran your code against it, and got valid output. Something else is going on.

Comment: my simple project, can you help me, please?: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18TJr_sHgUD9IT2TWSpYhy9spGwZlno3O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That looks like an character encoding issue in the screenshot there.

Comment: Yes, like screenshot. this error

Comment: Seems encoding problem - check [this out](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gdib-m6ux)

Comment: Please post all relevant information into the question via edit so that the full story is all in one place and your question can possibly reopened then possibly closed as a duplicate of a pre-existing encoding question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

The file encoding appears to be UCS-2 LE, from which [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) developed<sup>[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20060114213239/http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#23)</sup>. (also see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736184/1575353)).

Save the file with UTF-8 encoding. Instead of notepad, try using a different text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has a menu for choosing the encoding of the file. Then the PHP code can read the characters as desired. See demo [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fwqk-0h2f).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://web.archive.org/web/20060114213239/http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#23</sub>